# Can't get the ajax callback function to work?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following js part to save some data and when it's saved ok i like to hide the form and show a succes message.

I have this:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo dirname(WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.plugin_basename(__FILE__)); ?>/save.php",
                data: str,
                success: cb_success
            });
var cb_success = function(msg){
            alert('test '+ msg);
                        if(msg == "OK") 
                        {
                            result = '<div class="notification_ok">Thank you!</div>';
                            alert('test '+ result);
                            jQuery("#widget-firn").hide();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = msg;
                        }
                        jQuery(this).html(result);
                    /
                }
```

The first alert does show OK , but the if(msg == "OK") doesn't seem to work???

Comment: presumably because msg != "OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `alert(msg)` returns "OK" yet `msg=="OK` does not work, try forcing `msg` `toString()` as it may not be that, and the reason `alert` does show it as one is because alert often does a `toString()` automatically.

So try:

```
msg.toString() == "OK"
```

If that doesn't work, then inspect what exactly `msg` is by using `console.log(msg)` for example.

Comment: hmm i tried both your sugegestions toString() didn't work (i totally thought it would) and inspecting console.log("msg equals: ".msg); returns the expected OK

Comment: instead of forcing it into a string, just do `console.log(msg)` (nothing else, so you can see is it just text or is it infact an array, object or something else)

Comment: @niklas, yep i tried console.log(msg) and it just returns OK so it looks like just text

Comment: @alex try console.log(msg.length) and console.log(typeof msg) and make sure they return 2 and string.

Comment: @nikla did what you told me to do and it returns 3 and string . So i guess there's a space or other char being returned. i am going to check if i can find the xtra character

Comment: @alex Sounds like you got something else in there than just "OK", probably a space as you mentioned.

Comment: @nikla, i think i have narrowed it down to the following. In save.php i include wp-load.php which also inlcudes a couple of files. How can i strip out every possible empty line from a include php file??? ps: tx for taking the time

Comment: @alex try $.trim(msg.toString()) == "OK"

Comment: ok huuray found a nice fix by first including the following file which fix the empty line problem http://wejn.org/stuff/wejnswpwhitespacefix.php